# Multiple left joins with aggregation on same table causes huge performance hit in SAP HANA

Tags: hana

I am joining two tables on HANA and, to get some statistics, I am LEFT joining the items table 3 times to get a total count, number of entries processed and number of errors, as shown below.

This is a dev system and the items table has only 1500 items. But the query below runs for 17 seconds.

When I remove any of the three aggregation terms (but leave the corresponding JOIN in place), the query executes almost immediately.

I have also tried adding indexes on the fields used in the specific JOINs, but that makes no difference.

```
select rk.guid, rk.run_id, rk.status, rk.created_at, rk.created_by, 
count( distinct rp.guid ), 
count( distinct rp2.guid ), 
count( distinct rp3.guid )
    from zbsbpi_rk as rk
    left join zbsbpi_rp as rp
      on rp.header = rk.guid
    left join zbsbpi_rp as rp2
      on rp2.header = rk.guid
     and rp2.processed = 'X'
    left join zbsbpi_rp as rp3
      on rp3.header = rk.guid
     and rp3.result_status = 'E'
    where rk.run_id = '0000000010'
    group by rk.guid, run_id, status, created_at, created_by
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My apologies, but I forgot that I had posted this question here. I had posted the same question at answers.sap.com after not getting any joy here: https://answers.sap.com/questions/172096/multiple-left-joins-with-aggregation-on-same-table.html

I eventually came up with the solution, which was a bit of a "doh!" moment:

```
  select rk.guid, rk.run_id, rk.status, rk.created_at, rk.created_by,
    count( distinct rp.guid ), 
    count( distinct rp2.guid ), 
    count( distinct rp3.guid )
    from zbsbpi_rk as rk
    join zbsbpi_rp as rp
      on rp.header = rk.guid
    left join zbsbpi_rp as rp2
      on rp2.guid = rp.guid
     and rp2.processed = 'X'
    left join zbsbpi_rp as rp3
      on rp3.guid = rp.guid
     and rp3.result_status = 'E'
    where rk.run_id = '0000000010'
    group by rk.guid, run_id, status, created_at, created_by
```

The subsequent left joins needed only to be joined to the first join on the same table, as the first join contained a superset of all the records anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can re-write you query to improve the performance:

```
select rk.guid, rk.run_id, rk.status, rk.created_at, rk.created_by, 
count( distinct rp.guid ), 
count( distinct (CASE WHEN rp.processed = 'X' then rp.guid else null end) ), 
count( distinct (CASE WHEN rp.result_status = 'E' then rp.guid else null end))
    from zbsbpi_rk as rk
    left join zbsbpi_rp as rp
      on rp.header = rk.guid
where rk.run_id = '0000000010'
    group by rk.guid, run_id, status, created_at, created_by
```

I'm not entirely sure if the *count distinct case construct* will work on hana but you may try.